# Does this 'cyclic Lipschitzianity' have a name?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, lipschitz-functions

I am wondering if the following classes of functions have a name and if they play a role in some branch of analysis. For $L\geq0$, define $C_L$ as
$$C_L = \{f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R: |f(x,y)-f(x',y)+f(x',y')-f(x,y')|\leq L|x-x'||y-y'|\}\,.$$

Note that if $f$ depends only on $x$ (or only on $y$), then it is in $C_0$, and so it il in $C_L$ for all $L$. This means that $f$ can be extremely irregular and yet be in $C_0$.

If $\partial x\partial y f$ exists everywhere then the fact that it is everywhere bounded by $L$ is equivalent to $f$ being in $C_L$.

An elementary property of these functions is that if $f\in C_L$ and for some $y$ we have that $x\mapsto f(x, y)$ is $M$-Lipschitz, then we have that $x\mapsto f(x, y')$ is $M+L|y-y'|$-Lipschitz for all $y'$.

Note that $f$ being Lipschitz is not enough for this property to be true. For example $f(x, y)=|x-y|$ is not in $C_L$ for any $L$.

Comment: Lipschitzianity, that's an interesting word

Comment: I have not seen it. The choice of product in $\leq L|x-x'||y-y'|$ seems a bit strange. What if $|x-x'|$ is very small? Or even $=0$?

Comment: @markvs well if it is 0 then the inequality always holds, as the LHS is 0 as well.

Comment: The problem is if $|x-x'|$ is very small, but $|y-y'|$ is large but the product is small.

Comment: @markvs why is it a problem?

Comment: The RHS is too small comparing to the LHS? I do not know exactly why it is a problem. If you think it is fine, it is OK. If it helps solving a problem, it is good.